# SFDX source deploy antivirus scanning

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment-api, source

I have a jenkins server runnig a sfdx source deploy command.

Compared with mdapi it is much slow. In my case 20 min more, but I found out that anti-malware of the server anti virus, is scanning the outbound files from a node.js process that is running along with the deployment.

So I am trying to find information about what kind of outbound files are produced and deployed with that cli command to think on some exception rule for the antivirus.

Anyone has any info on this?